# php session_destroy all clear all sessions except the one running the code

Tags: php, session

I have been looking for a way to log all my users out except the one activating this command? if there a way to do this... I have the following code below but I am not even sure if it 100% works as it said "try"

```
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
```

So I want to clear all the sessions (session_destroy) on each session except for the session viewing the page?? is this possible..

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case more right way - create custom code to logout all users. For example I can suggest this solutions:

1. You can store in database special parameter `last_users_logout_time` and when user login then store in $_SESSION array variable `user_login_time`. And in every page you can check if `user_login_time` < `last_users_logout_time` or `user_login_time` is null then logout user. Very simple. For ignore specified user you can add parameter `except_logout_user_id` into database
2. More "right way" - store $_SESSION data in database and just run `DELETE` query for all `session` table except specified user